# Magento email_queue sending mails every 2 minutes

Tags: magento-1.9, email, upgrade

I am recieving order mails every 2 minutes. When i turn of the cron. It doesnt send any emails anymore. 
I have updated my magento to 1.9.2.2 and the problems started.

Now if someone magento sends a mail it is places in the core_email_queue table. But when the mail is actueally sended it is not updating the row proccessed_at in the core_email_queue. Or doest this need to be empty.

How can is solve to problem? because i worry about my email reputation.

Comment: So you have the cron off ?

Comment: Is the core_email_queue_clean_up cron activated?

Comment: I think you need the cron to send emails.

Answer (score 1):

As of Magento 1.9.1 magento introduced an email_queue to send emails based on your cron configuration. There are two cron tasks that run:

```
<core_email_queue_send_all>
    <schedule><cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
    <run><model>core/email_queue::send</model></run>
</core_email_queue_send_all>
<core_email_queue_clean_up>
    <schedule><cron_expr>0 0 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
    <run><model>core/email_queue::cleanQueue</model></run>
</core_email_queue_clean_up>
```

Basically It will send all emails in the queue every minute and then every day it will clear out the table with emails that have been processed.